# curl_init and curl_setopt equivalent of ruby

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

What is the curl_init and curl_setopt equivalent of ruby?

```
$apikey='xxx';
$apisecret='xxx';
$nonce=time();
$uri='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/getopenorders?apikey='.$apikey.'&nonce='.$nonce;
$sign=hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$apisecret);
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
$execResult = curl_exec($ch);
$obj = json_decode($execResult);
```

I am using restclient.

```
response = RestClient.post(uri, "sign" => sign, "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

But I am getting the error

```
RestClient::MethodNotAllowed (405 Method Not Allowed):
```

Can I use Rest-client. or should I need use some else. What is the equivalent of the php code

Comment: maybe it should be `get`, not `post`?

Comment: @UriAgassi - Can you add this as answer. I ll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `RestClient::MethodNotAllowed` hints to the fact that the call *method* (`POST` in your example) is not allowed on the server.

Make sure that the method you use in your client call is supported but the server for that URI.

```
response = RestClient.get(uri, "sign" => sign, "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```